# Expand entire accordion using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to incorporate a button that expands all of my accordion at once. I have tried the following but the button does not do anything. Any help would be appreciated as I cannot find the error.

I am trying to use the following button:

```
<button id="toggleAccordions" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">Open / Close</button>
```

To expand all aspects of the following accordion:

```
<div id="a1" role="tablist" class="accordion extend-right0">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="a12010~2019heading">
            <h3 class="card-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#a12010~2019" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="a12010~2019">
                    <div class="container"><span></span>2010~2019</div>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="a12010~2019" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="a12010~2019heading" data-parent="#a1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>2010~2012</h4>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Programme</th>
                                <th scope="col">Graduation</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <td>President</td>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Ph.D</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <h4>2012~2014</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="a12000~2009heading">
            <h3 class="card-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#a12000~2009" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="a12000~2009">
                    <div class="container"><span></span>2000~2009</div>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="a12000~2009" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="a12000~2009heading" data-parent="#a1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>2000~2001</h4>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Programme</th>
                                <th scope="col">Graduation</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <td>President</td>
                                <td>name</td>
                                <td>Ph.D.</td>
                                <td>9 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the following js, but it does not expand:

```
$(function() {
$('#toggleAccordions').on('click', function(e) {

$('.accordion .collapse').toggleClass('show');
})
});
```

Comment: you want to toggle class 'show' on all elements with 'collapse' class under div with class 'accordion'?

Comment: yes that is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no issue with the code, I have prepared a small demo.

Edit: The issue was with loading jquery after the js function being executed. Making jquery load before the function execution worked.

```js
$(function() {
$('#toggleAccordions').on('click', function(e) {
$('.accordion .collapse').toggleClass('show');
})
});
```

```css
.collapse {

  display: none;

}

.collapse.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggleAccordions" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">Open / Close</button>
<div id="a1" role="tablist" class="accordion extend-right0">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="a12010~2019heading">
            <h3 class="card-title">
                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#a12010~2019" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="a12010~2019">
                    <div class="container"><span></span>2010~2019</div>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="a12010~2019" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="a12010~2019heading" data-parent="#a1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>2010~2012</h4>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Programme</th>
                                <th scope="col">Graduation</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <td>President</td>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Ph.D</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <h4>2012~2014</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="a12000~2009heading">
            <h3 class="card-title">
                <a class="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#a12000~2009" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="a12000~2009">
                    <div class="container"><span></span>2000~2009</div>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="a12000~2009" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="a12000~2009heading" data-parent="#a1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>2000~2001</h4>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"></th>
                                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Programme</th>
                                <th scope="col">Graduation</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <td>President</td>
                                <td>name</td>
                                <td>Ph.D.</td>
                                <td>9 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Odd. I copied and pasted your code into custom HTML on wordpress and it does not work. The button does nothing when clicked.

Comment: ok I got it. can you tell me if you have placed both js and html in the same file?

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted your exact code into the same page in a custom HTML block

Comment: I have found the issue? I initially had the jquery source and script in the header. I just moved it to the footer and it works..

Comment: please make a note in your answer to have the source and script in the footer and I will select your answer as the correct solution.